# Can "flourish" be used as an active verb?

Tags: verbs, transitive-verbs

I would like to say the following:

"Taking this job would allow for these ideas to flourish".

But I'm wondering whether I can say it in an active manner:

"Taking this job would allow for me to flourish these ideas".

The dictionary definition of flourish is "grow or develop", so using it in this way would logically make sense, but I just have never seen it before!

Comment: *Flourish* can be a transitive verb. [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flourish#flourish__10). I don't think your sentence is an appropriate use, though; its meaning has diverged from the intransive sense.

Comment: I think that its OK to write it as an active verb if your writing a note to yourself, but if you are going to share it with others than I would use proper grammar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope! *Flourish* is an ***intransitive*** verb. It can't take a direct object.

Take another look at the dictionary and you'll probably see some cryptic abbreviation like "*v.intr.*"

> Plants **grow**. *(ok, intransitive use of "grow")*
>   I **grow** plants.  *(ok, transitive use of "grow")*
>   Plants **flourish**. *(ok, intransitive use of "flourish")*
>   I **flourish** plants. *(wrong, but see below)*

There *is* also a transitive sense of *flourish,* but it has a totally different meaning. If you *flourish* a zucchini squash, you're not helping it to grow. You're wielding it dramatically as a weapon.

(Technically, all of these sentences use the active voice; passive voice would be *Plants are grown.* But I see what you mean by "active": you want yourself to appear as the agent in the sentence. You'll just have to use a different verb.)

Comment: Are you saying that 'flourish' and 'flourish' are _different [words](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/verb)_?

Comment: That's not what I meant to say, so I changed it.

Comment: Actually, "flourish" also means "something resembling flour".